# Is there a way to restart a queue in a specific logic

Tags: laravel

I have a daemon running, which I am using for a socket connection, is there any way to restart this daemon inside the code when a specific login applies. Any command? Restarting the daemon queue inside that queue

```
            \Ratchet\Client\connect($this->stream)->then(function ($ws) {

        $ws->on('message', function ($data) {
            
        });
        $ws->on('close', function ($code = null, $reason = null) {
            //RESTART THE QUEUE THIS SOCKET BELONGS TO
            Log::alert( "userData: WebSocket Connection closed! ({$code} - {$reason})" . PHP_EOL);
        });
```

there are multiple sockets running (dispatching from the same job), and i want to restart all of them if one is closed

Comment: could you be more descriptive sample code or more?

Comment: Just edited can you relook please?